# @RequestMapping doesn't accept multiple values in headers

Tags: spring-mvc

I added a custom parameter in the request header. Why is it not possible to have multiple values in headers for @RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/header", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers={"version=1.0.1","version=1.0.2"})
public @ResponseBody String byHeaderValue();
```

I tried too the below code but no way it doesn't work:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/mapping/header", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers={"version=1.0.1,1.0.2"})
public @ResponseBody String byHeaderValue();
```

But if I make 2 separate methods, it works:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/header", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="version=1.0.1")
public @ResponseBody String byHeaderValue1();

@RequestMapping(value="/mapping/header", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="version=1.0.2")
public @ResponseBody String byHeaderValue2();
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to specify 2 headers with the same name. Header names must be unique.

Comment: I tried with headers={"v1.0.1=1.0.1","v1.0.2=1.0.2"}, it doesn't work too. So the problem is not because the name of the parameter is the same. Thx for your response.

Comment: To discard any doubt with the use of ".", I tried with: headers={"version1=1","version2=2"}. No way, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've added an alternative solution to go around the issue you are having. This should work.

Comment: thank you for your efforts, but I try to select the right method from the server side with this header parameter. So I don't need the version client side (don't need to send version to the client with response object). The version parameter in the header is sent by the client

Comment: I see, sorry for the confusion. Have you tried to annotate 2 String method parameters with @RequestHeader?

Comment: My aim is to preselect the method with annotations. If I use @RequestHeader as a method parameter, this means the selection of the method is already done. For info in my example, I put only version 1 and 2, but I will have a lot of versions.